# Erro ao converter inteiro no JS de um input HTML

Tags: javascript, html

No curso que estou fazendo foi passando um exercício que tentei de outra forma que o professor ensinou e acabou dando errado. Já consegui fazer da forma que rodasse certo. Mas ainda não sei porque deu errado na minha modificação. segue o código:

```
<body>
<h1>Somando 2 numeros</h1>
<input type="number" id="num1"> +
<input type="number" id="num2">
<input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
<div id="soma">Resultado</div>
<script>
function somar(){
    var n1 = Number(window.document.getElementById('num1'))
    var n2 = Number(window.document.getElementById('num2'))
    var res = window.document.getElementById('soma')
    var s = n1 + n2
    res.innerText = (s)
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você somou os elementos `<input>` obtidos por [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) o que faltou foi somar os valores dos atributos [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) de cada `<input>`.

```html
<body>
  <h1>Somando 2 numeros</h1>
  <input type="number" id="num1"> +
  <input type="number" id="num2">
  <input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
  <div id="soma">Resultado</div>
  <script>
    function somar() {
      var n1 = Number(window.document.getElementById('num1').value) //note o .value que não tinha antes
      var n2 = Number(window.document.getElementById('num2').value)
      var res = window.document.getElementById('soma')
      var s = n1 + n2
      res.innerText = (s)
    }
  </script>
```